# Parent view for RelativeLayout doesn't catch scroll gesture

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have some view hierarchy

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TOP_VIEW_LAYOUT"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <BASearchView
        android:id="@+id/SEARCH_FIELD"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">       
    </BASearchView>

    <BalanceView
        android:id="@+id/CARD_INFO_FIELD"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

where `public class BASearchView extends LinearLayout` and `public class BalanceView extends RelativeLayout`. Also I have `public class TopView extends LinearLayout` which uses `TOP_VIEW_LAYOUT`.. So, time for question. I'm trying to dispatch user events in `TopView` class

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent( MotionEvent event ) {
    Log.i( TAG, "dispatchTouchEvent() has been called" );
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent( event );
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent( event );
}
```

where mGestureDetector is object of SimpleGestureDetector

```
private SimpleOnGestureListener mGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling( MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float vx, float vy ){
        Log.i( TAG, "TopView fling has been detected" );
        return false;
    }
        public boolean onScroll (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            Log.i( TAG, "TopView scroll has been detected" );
            return false;
        }
    };
```

and I have a problem..
`onScroll` (from gesture detector) is called only if start point inside `BASearchView`, not in `BalanceView`.. Why??!! I can't understand :(

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. 
I've found an ugly solution..
Simple I've added empty `onClickListener` for `BalanceView` and it's become to work

```
    public class BalanceView extends RelativeLayout {

        public BalanceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            init();
        }
        private void init() {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            inflater.inflate( R.layout.balance_view, this, true );

            setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {                  
                }           
            });
            //some code..
        }

       //some class code...   
}
```

can anyone explain that? )